# Get last json data from a streaming url

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

I'm using PHP curl to get JSON data from a streaming URL (an URL that keeps loading new data every 1 second without stop), when I try to open that link using PHP curl it doesn't give me any data, just a blank page !

Can someone please help me to resolve this? This is the link :

[The link here](https://api.fm-track.com/object-coordinates-stream?version=1&object_id=180f2666-ea37-11e7-9869-7f695b77848b&api_key=_Xl0rjBoU2YCp0anj79eWrgKcZFDDxr4)

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.fm-track.com/object-coordinates-stream?version=1&object_id=180f2666-ea37-11e7-9869-7f695b77848b&api_key=_Xl0rjBoU2YCp0anj79eWrgKcZFDDxr4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all("/:\"(.*?)\",/", $result, $matches);
$lat = $matches[1][2];
$lng = $matches[1][3];
$vitesse = $matches[1][6];
$derniersignalgps = $matches[1][1];
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please paste in the code you have tried so someone can work off that.

Comment: Hi,i added the code i'm using

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to use curl as you need to read the observable stream, not jsut the initial response.

You probably need to use [`stream-open`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-open.php) or [`stream-read`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-read.php)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply ! i've never used stream-open or read !! i only need to get the last json data so i can use it in my script.